# How to use Powershell to uninstall printers that were install by a print server

Tags: powershell, printers

I am trying to uninstall network printers that were installed using a print server. My current PS script will only uninstall printers that were mapped. I've included my script below. Any help  would be appreciated.

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where{$_.name -notlike 'microsoft print to PDF‘}| foreach{$_.delete()}`

Comment: Does changing your where argument get you closer? `where{$_.systemname -like "\\*"}`

Comment: No. That did not uninstall the printers.